# timelines and history files postgresql 9.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Can someone explain me the purpose of timelines and history files and the setting 'recovery_target_timeline' in recovery.conf.

The vague understanding I got from the postgresql 9.1 documentation is that when the slave completes recovery it switches to a new timeline to prevent overwriting of WALs of a previous timeline. I am not clear how this is used in a recovery scenario and the purpose of the .history file and the 'recovery_target_timeline' setting to 'latest'.

I am trying to understand what happens when I promote the slave to become the new master. It recovers and starts a new timeline before accepting read/write queries.

Now if I setup a new slave since I promoted the existing slave to master, does it need/use the history file generated by the previous slave (new master) to read the new WALs generated (by the new master) for continuous archiving/log shipping.

Thanks much.

Comment: The recovery_target_timeline is used to specify a timeline in the event that you are recovering after having already previously performed a point-in-time recovery, which creates divergent timelines. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES

Answer (score 0):

To understand timelines what you have to understand is that they are to avoid problems with MVCC and diverging timelines.  A good way to think about this is in the context of replication.  In Master/Slave streaming replication you don't want someone to bring the slave up as a master insert a bunch of information and then turn it back into a slave.  If you do this, the binary logs of the WAL segments can no longer run properly and you will get db corruption.

When you recover a slave to a new master it completes "recovery" and starts its own timeline.  From this point on, it is now the master and can not go back to being the slave without a rebuild.  This poses some issues for failover and fail back but the way to do this is to periodically fail back and forth with the old master rebuilding the db (using `pg_basebackup`) as a new slave.  This means each failover/failback is a new timeline.

Yes, this does impact failing over multiple servers, as the slaves have to change timelines.